# Is it possible to encrypt a piece of text with a password to produce an encrypted text that is the same length as the original text in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I have 2 variables: `text` and `password`. `text` is a bit of information I would like to encrypt and `password` is the password I would like to encrypt the text with. I understand how to encrypt text in Node.js, but what I need is different than anything I've seen so far.

My goal is to have a function process the text using the password, and generate something **REASONABLY CLOSE IN LENGTH** to the original text.

Here is what I've already come up with:

```js
class Encryptor {
    constructor(encryptionKey) {
        this.algorithm = "aes256";
        this.key = encryptionKey
    }
  
    encrypt(text) {
        var cipher = crypto.createCipher(this.algorithm, this.key);
        var encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');

        return encrypted;
    }
  
    decrypt(encrypted) {
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(this.algorithm, this.key);
        var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');

        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```js
let text = "I am some secret info"
let password = "password"
let encryptor = new Encryptor(password);
let encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(text);

console.log(text.length, encrypted.length)
```

This gives me an encrypted text about 2 times the length of the original. However, when used with a text like `magic...`, it is a little more than that.

So that brings me to my question: is there a way to encrypt a text with a password and produce encrypted text something close in length to the original text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring the length of the base64 encoded ciphertext.

If you need the output to be base64 encoded, then base64 encode the plaintext too and you will see they are about the same length.

If you don't need the output to be base64 encoded, then don't base64 encode the ciphertext and you will, again, see that they are about the same length.

You are just encoding the two messages using different encoding schemes. But they both have roughly the same amount of information content. Encode them both the same way and they will be roughly the same length.